# Shortcuts are Disappearing from the main menu / toolbar of "Kile"

Tags: menu, kile

Actually, I have found that, in the latest installation of KILE in Ubuntu 16.04,  (I have installed through Ubuntu Software Center...), all the shortcuts specified in main menu are disappeared... and I have been trying to get the previous menu where they were appeared correctly... but somehow, I couldn't obtain it...

Kindly help me in this regard...

For your perusal, I am attaching one screenshot.... where, for example you can see that, to convert my text into comment, I can't find the shortcut viz., <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>... likewise... all shortcuts have gone...

Reproducible: Always

As shown in the screenshot attached, I can't find - for example - the shortcut of "Comment" -- which is usually <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.....!

[image]

P.S. : I am using QMake version 2.01a
Using Qt version 4.8.7 in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`

Answer (score 1):

Try right clicking on the menu bar and un-locking it. Later you can choose in the same tab which toolbars appear under the option "Toolbars shown". If you miss a particular command you can also configure each toolbar in Settings--> Configure Toolbars.